# Problems with OBJLoader

Tags: three.js

Occasionally when I run my WebGL/Three.js environment, the scene does not render, no errors occur, after the obj is loaded up.

Feel free to check out the code.

[Thoscene.com](http://thoscene.com)

All help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Link produces a Magento branded error. Hard to help without seeing code, putting some in the question may be a good idea.

Comment: Sorry, just happened to be bad timing, the site is up now.